# How to get selected TreeViewItem items header?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeviewitem

I'm populating two-level TreeView from `Dictonary<int, string> myFirstDictionary` (for first level) and from `Dictionary<string, int> mySecondDictionary` (for 2nd level):

XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="myTreeView"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
TreeViewItem item;

foreach (var dict1 in myFirstDictionary)
{
     item = TreeViewItem();
     item.Header = dict1.Value;
     foreach (var dict2 in mySecondDictionary)
         if (dict1.Key == dict2.Value)
             item.Items.Add(dict2.Key);
     myTreeView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

This works just fine. I can easily get TreeViewItem's Header of first level using this code:

```
TreeVeiwItem tvi = myTreeView.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
MessageBox.Show(tvi.Header.ToString());
```

The problem is I don't know how to get second level TreeViewItem's Header (the one which is populated from `dict2.Key`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
TreeViewItem tvItem = null;
tvItem = ContainGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myTreeView.SelectedItem) as TreeViewItem;

MessageBox.Show(tvItem.Header);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to extract items header from any selected item.

```
string itemHeader = ((HeaderedItemsControl)myTreeView.SelectedItem ).Header.ToString()
```